# Is it useful to mark an old question (with answers) as duplicate of an older one?

Tags: discussion

I am talking about [How do I grant sudo privileges to an existing user?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/168280/how-do-i-grant-sudo-privileges-to-an-existing-user), which is over a year old and has 4 answers with an accepted answer.

This question just turned up in the CloseVote queue as possible duplicate. I'd say to leave it open, what is your take?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, remember most of our traffic comes from search engines, which means that we should have duplicates pointing to one canonical source instead of spread over the site, this also includes old questions.

Before I mark things like this though I usually compare answers between both, in some cases a merge is more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that the scope of the question is the same. Remember that a same answer can apply for several things with some tweaks.

Also, is not the same asking *"How to do X?"*, *"How X do that?"* and *How can I make Y to do X?*